# Swift How to Listen for Changes in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, real-time, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm using the AWS Mobile Hub to provide a backend service. So far I understand how to upload data into the DynamoDB and how to retrieve the data. **I'm wondering if there's a way to listen for a change in the database without using push notifications.** Say another user changed a value in a table, how can I detect this change on the front-end with Swift.

I've seen people suggesting DynamoDB streams, but I can't find its documentation for Swift, and I'm not sure if that actually allows the front end to listen for changes in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for docs about DynamoDB streams. It **should** work with front end to listen to changes. You can find their sdk in supported languages at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_ListStreams.html). But I did find the documentation of Swift either.

Or perhaps you can check Pubsub, [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/).